# Listing users for certain DB with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

## What I'm trying to acheive

I'm trying to fetch users for a certain database.

## What I did so far

I was able to find function to list the databases or create users but none  for listing the users, I thought about invoking an arbitrary command such as `show users` but I could find any way to do it.

## Current code

```
#/usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db = client.this_mongo
```

## Trial and error

I can see the DB names and print them but nothing further:

```
db_names = client.database_names()

#users = db.command("show users")
for document in db_names:
    print(document)
#cursor = db.add_user('TestUser','Test123',roles={'role':'read'})
```

If there was only a function that could fetch the users cursor so I can iterate over it it would be great.

## EDIT

### Working solution

```
#/usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db = client.this_mongo

# This is the line I added with the help of @salmanwahed
listing = db.command('usersInfo')

for document in listing['users']:
    print document['user'] +" "+ document['roles'][0]['role']
```

Thank you all and @salmanwahed specifically!

Comment: I am eager to know if my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: @salmanwahed, sorry for the delay, I had some python json issues I had to resolve before I could tell you it's fine, I'm updating the document in a minute with the working results with showing the users list for a certain DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute the [`usersInfo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/#dbcmd.usersInfo) command to fetch the users data. Like:

```
db.command('usersInfo')
```

It will return you a result like this: (I had created the `testingdb` for testing)

```
{u'ok': 1.0,
 u'users': [{u'_id': u'testingdb.TestUser',
   u'db': u'testingdb',
   u'roles': [{u'db': u'testingdb', u'role': u'read'}],
   u'user': u'TestUser'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that works without elevation (even though it looks at a portion of the admin collection).  A db user can always see their own information.

```
#/usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

username = "myDBReader"

uri = 'mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/'

client = MongoClient(uri)

db = client.admin

listing = db.command({"usersInfo": username }

print(username, "has roles:")
pprint.pprint(db.command({"usersInfo": username })['users'][0]['roles'])
```