# How to run the getRole command using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I want to check whether a role exists in a `mongodb`, before I create a new one . I tried to do it the following way:

```
result = self.client[database].command("getRole", name=app_name)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
msg = msg or "%s"
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: no such command: 'getRole', bad cmd: '{ getRole: 1, name: "test" }'
```

I am referring to this database command: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getRole/

For createRole I can execute the command: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/#db.createRole

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562042/listing-users-for-certain-db-with-pymongo

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I could workaround the problem like this, but it is not exactly the same thing, since the other questions asks for a user and I am just concerned about one specific role.

Comment: If you try creating a role that exists you get an error. What this reason for not applying  _ask for forgiveness and not permission_ philosophy here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shell methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) `db.*` are different from [Database commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/).

Using the [`roleInfo command`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/rolesInfo/#dbcmd.rolesInfo) you can get information for a particular role.

```
db.command({
    'rolesInfo': {'role': 'noremove','db': 'test'},
    'showPrivileges': True, 'showBuiltinRoles': True
})
```

The above command returns a result in this form **when there is a matching role**:

```
{'ok': 1.0,
 'roles': [{'db': 'test',
   'inheritedPrivileges': [{'actions': ['find', 'insert', 'update'],
     'resource': {'collection': 'test', 'db': 'test'}}],
   'inheritedRoles': [],
   'isBuiltin': False,
   'privileges': [{'actions': ['find', 'insert', 'update'],
     'resource': {'collection': 'test', 'db': 'test'}}],
   'role': 'noremove',
   'roles': []}]}
```

**When there is no matching role**, you get this result:

```
{'ok': 1.0, 'roles': []}
```

**Checking that a role exists** falls to checking for the length of the "roles" list in the returned result as follow:

```
noremove_role = db.command({
    'rolesInfo': {'role': 'noremove','db': 'test'},
    'showPrivileges': True, 'showBuiltinRoles': True
})

if not len(noremove_role['roles']):
    # create role
    pass
```

### Is there a better way?

Yes, in keeping with **ask forgiveness not permission** philosophy, create the role and handle the resulting exception from trying to add an existing role.

```
from pymongo.errors import DuplicateKeyError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()

try:
    db.command(
        'createRole', 'noremove',
        privileges=[{
            'actions': ['insert', 'update', 'find'],
            'resource': {'db': 'test', 'collection': 'test'}
        }],
        roles=[])
except DuplicateKeyError:
    logger.error('Role already exists.')
    pass
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I was not aware of this. Regarding the forgiveness approach: I was not entirely precise in the question, I was also interested in the return values of the getRole command to check the current permissions. But your response clarifies that all.